# How to detect the IsolatedStorage Used Space in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone, isolatedstorage

As per the title, how can I determine the used IsolatedStorage space in a Windows Phone Application?

Answer (score 0):

You can know available free space and the used space.

```
try
{
    using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        Int64 curAvail = store.AvailableFreeSpace;
        var used = store.Quota - curAvail;
    }
}

catch (IsolatedStorageException)
{
    // TODO: Handle that store could not be accessed.

}
```

Comment: Thanks for post.But the IsolatedStorageFile didn't have the UsedSize property. I am developping mango apps.

Comment: I run this code,but i get the value is too big.It seems not the Application used space value.

Comment: IsolatedStorageFile.UsedSize is the correct method, but is not exposed as part of Silverlight for WP7.  What is the purpose for obtaining this value?  Maybe you can approach your issue in a different way.